# XML : merging  xml file into nodes of another xml file 

Tags: c#, xml, file, merge

I have two XML files that I want to merge in first file’s nodes

First file 
Toc.xml

```
<toc>
<item id ="c12">
<english>book1</english>
<french>book1</french>
</title>
</item>
<item id = "part1"/>
<item id = "part2"/>
<item id = "part3"/>
</toc>
```

Second file will be updated every time after running transformation with XML files(part 1,2,3)
Second file :while running transformation with part1.xml

```
<item id = “part 1”>
<title>
<english>part1</english>
<french>part1</french>
</title></item>
```

Second file :while running transformation with part2.xml

```
<item id = “part 2”>
<title>
<english>part2</english>
<french>part2</french>
</title>
</item>
```

Result in Toc file

```
  <toc>
  <item id ="c12">
  <english>book1</english>
  <french>book1</french>
  </title>
  </item>
  <item id = "part1">
  <title>
  <english>part1</english>
  <french>part1</french>
  </title>
  </item>
  <item id = "part2">
  <title>
  <english>part2</english>
  <french>part2</french>
  </title>
  </item>
  <item id = "part3">
  <title>
  <english>part3</english>
  <french>part3</french>
  </title>
  </item>
  </toc>
```

I tried using import node but it gives me errors(root element is missing) and other error "The node to be inserted is from a different document context"

Here is the code i tried

```
   XmlDocument temp = new XmlDocument();
    temp.Load("secondfile.xml");
    XmlDocument toc = new XmlDocument();
    toc.Load(toc.xml);
    XmlNodeList toclist = toc.SelectNodes("/toc/item");
    foreach (XmlNode tocnode in toclist) 
    {XmlNodeList tempnodelist = temp.SelectNodes("/item");
    foreach (XmlNode tempnode in tempnodelist)
    { XmlNode importnode = toc.ImportNode(tempnode, true);
    toc.appendNode(importnode, tocnode);
    }}
```

you are right. My question was not clear. i changed que to be more specific. i hope you will find it more clean this time.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you make your question either more general (what's a good way of merging multiple XML files based on criteria X?) or more specific (these three lines of code produce this exact error message - what am I doing wrong?). As is, there are too many poorly formatted fragments of code to make it easy to tell what's going on or which of the several questions relate to what fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item id = “part 1”>
  <title>
    <english>part1</english>
    <french>part1</french>
  </title>
</item>

<toc>
  <item id ="c12">
    <english>book1</english>
    <french>book1</french>  
  </item>
  <item id = "part1"/>
  <item id = "part2"/>
  <item id = "part3"/>
</toc>
```

The answer might be:

```
XmlDocument mainDocument = new XmlDocument();
mainDocument.Load("toc.xml");
XmlDocument tempDocument = new XmlDocument();
tempDocument.Load("part1.xml");

XmlNodeList tempList = tempDocument.GetElementsByTagName("item");
string id=tempList[0].GetAttribute("id");//gets the id attribute value

XmlNode mainRoot = mainDocument.DocumentElement; //gets the root node of the main document toc.xml
XmlNodeList mainList = mainRoot.SelectNodes("/toc");
XmlNode itemNode = mainList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/toc/item[@id=\"" + id + "\"]")); //select the item node according to the id attribute value

XmlNode tempitemNode = tempList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/toc/item[@id=\"" + id + "\"]/title")); //select the title node of the part1, part2 or part3 files

itemNode.AppendChild(tempitemNode.FirstChild);
itemNode.AppendChild(tempitemNode.LastChild);

mainDocument.Save("toc.xml");
```

Something like that